# Embedding ffplay window into tkinter frame by using SetParent win32gui function

Tags: python, winapi, tkinter, ffmpeg, win32gui

i'm using to embed the ffplay window into my tkinter frame.

that's my code:

```
file = "path/to/the/file.mp4"
command = subprocess.Popen(["ffplay","-i","%s"%file],stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, text=True,)
pid = gw.getWindowsWithTitle('%s'%file) #getting the hwnd of the ffplay window
hwnd = re.findall(r'\d+',str(pid))
x = int(videoWidget.winfo_x()) #video widget is the target tkinter frame
y =int(videoWidget.winfo_y())
width =  int(videoWidget.winfo_width())
height =  int(videoWidget.winfo_height())
win32gui.MoveWindow(int(hwnd[-1]), int(x), int(y),int(width) , int(height), 1) # trying to move the ffplay window to the videowidget geometry 
win32gui.SetParent(int(hwnd[-1]),int(stream_id)) #trying to set the parent of the ffplay window to the videowidget, that should show the ffplay window in the tkinter frame
```

the code run without any error, but the both ffplay window and tkinter window stop responding without any error

if any one can help me in this i'll be thankful

Comment: You can't do this. [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683) explains why.

Comment: Try [`FFPyPlayer`](http://matham.github.io/ffpyplayer/player.html).

Comment: Hi @IInspectable, i want to make video editor with graphical user interface. using ffplay will help in seeing the video filter without saving it (preview video filter)

Comment: Hi @acw1668, that's not help in my case. thank you for your answer

Comment: @IInspectable Why can't one open both windows on one process? You can use the affinity setting for this (accessible through win32 packages).

Comment: `Popen` crates a new process. If you wish to play your reparenting tricks you'll need to use FFMpeg (the library) from within your process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root cause of stopping responding:
`stdout=PIPE` and/or `stderr=PIPE`.
It blocks the output of `ffmpeg` and cause a deadlock.

You could create a new console for the output of the `ffmpeg`.

My test sample:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE
import pygetwindow as gw
import win32gui
import regex as re
import time
file = "path/to/the/file.mp4"
proc = subprocess.Popen(["ffplay","-i","%s"%file], creationflags = CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)

time.sleep(2) #make sure the window has been started and available to find.
pid = gw.getWindowsWithTitle('%s'%file) #getting the hwnd of the ffplay window
hwnd = re.findall(r'\d+',str(pid))
print(hwnd)
x = 0 #video widget is the target tkinter frame
y = 0
width =  800
height =  500
win32gui.MoveWindow(int(hwnd[-1]), int(x), int(y),int(width) , int(height), 1) # trying to move the ffplay window to the videowidget geometry
```

In addition, you should make sure you have started the window before calling `getWindowsWithTitle`.

Comment: This is not a solution. It merely postpones the inevitable dead-lock.

Comment: Hi @IInspectable. So,you mean that there's no permanent solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment, I would like to point out that you can pipe stdout to subprocess.DEVNULL, `stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL` to prevent the deadlock.